# MKOverlays Combining Image Tiles And KML

Tags: ios, kml, mkoverlay

I am trying to display tiled images with a kml overlay on top of the tiled images (code below) and am receiving the following error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MKPolyline tilesInMapRect:zoomScale:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Does anyone have any suggestions as to whether or not I am approaching the multiple overlays correctly or why I am getting this error?

Thanks in advance!

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize the map overlay with tiles in the app's bundle.
    NSString *tileDirectory = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tiles"];

    MapOverlay *overlay1 = [[MapOverlay alloc] initWithDirectory:tileDirectory];

    // Locate the path to the route.kml file in the application's bundle
    // and parse it with the KMLParser.

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"route" ofType:@"kml"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    kmlParser = [[KMLParser alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [kmlParser parseKML];

    // Add all of the MKOverlay objects parsed from the KML file to the map.
    NSArray *overlay2 = [kmlParser overlays];

    [map addOverlay:overlay1];
    [map addOverlays:overlay2];

    // Set the starting location.
    CLLocationCoordinate2D startingLocation;
    startingLocation.latitude = 0.00;
    startingLocation.longitude =-0.00;

    map.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(startingLocation, 4600, 4600);
    [map setCenterCoordinate:startingLocation];       
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay1
{
    MapOverlayView *view = [[MapOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay1];
    view.overlayAlpha = 1.0;
    return view;
}


- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay2:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay2
{
    return [kmlParser viewForOverlay:overlay2];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

At least the `viewForOverlay` delegate method is not implemented correctly.

You've written two methods: `mapView:viewForOverlay:` and `mapView:viewForOverlay2:`.

But the map view will only always call `mapView:viewForOverlay:` since that is the method name defined by the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol.

The `mapView:viewForOverlay2:` method will be ignored and not called by the map view.

So what happens is that when the `overlay2` overlay array is added to the map, it calls the `mapView:viewForOverlay:` method which creates a `MapOverlayView` for the overlay (instead of getting the overlay view from `kmlParser`).  This may cause issues (maybe `MapOverlayView` only handles `MapOverlay`-type overlays).

All overlays should be handled in the `mapView:viewForOverlay:` method.
To handle multiple types of overlays, check the `overlay` class and handle accordingly:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MapOverlay class]])
    {
        MapOverlayView *view = [[MapOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
        view.overlayAlpha = 1.0;
        return view;
    }

    //if not a MapOverlay, get from kmlParser...
    return [kmlParser viewForOverlay:overlay];
}
```

Remove the `mapView:viewForOverlay2:` method.